# Copying of one data structure to another in C

Tags: c, struct

In the following code, can we copy `yy` to `xx`? If not, is there another way? Do we have to use pointer or something else?

```
typedef unsigned int UINT32
typedef struct
{
    UINT32 a : 4; 
    UINT32 b: 2;      
    UINT32 c: 2;
    UINT32 d: 4;
    UINT32 e: 4;
    UINT32 f: 8; 
    UINT32 g: 8;
}Word;

Word *xx , *yy;
xx = yy;
xx->a = 1;
```

Comment: Did you try this code?

Comment: if i try to give xx->a = 1; in next instruction, i am not able to run the code..

Comment: Sure, because `xx` is not allocated.

Comment: Please read about dynamic memory allocation, and come back!

Comment: If you use Word xx, yy; (i.e. local variables, not dynamically allocated) then you can assign xx = yy and you can set e.g. xx.a = 1

Comment: #include <stdio.h> #include <stdlib.h> typedef unsigned int UINT32; typedef struct { UINT32 a : 4; UINT32 b: 2; UINT32 c: 2; UINT32 d: 4; UINT32 e: 4; UINT32 f: 8; UINT32 g: 8; }Word; Word *xx , *yy; int main() { xx = yy; xx->a = 1; printf("%d",xx->a); return 0; }-- I am not able to run this code

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can assign one structure to each other. Every member would be copied.

In your examples, `*xx = *yy` is equivalent to:

```
xx->a = yy->a;
xx->b = yy->b;
//...
xx->g = yy->g;
```

notice that you must copy `*yy` in `*xx`, not the pointer `yy` into the pointer `xx`.
Notice also that you didn't initialize the pointers, nor the structures. You should go something like

```
Word a, b;
b.a = ...;
b.b = ...;
...
b.g = ...;
Word* xx = &a;
Word* yy = &b;
*xx = *yy; //equivalent to a = b;
```

You must pay attention to struct containing pointers: the value of the pointer is copied in that case, hence the underlying object, if any, is the same one. Depending on the semanthics of your code, this could or could not be what you mean.

Comment: if i try to give xx->a = 1; in next instruction, i am not able to run the code..

Comment: if i try to give xx->a = 1; in next instruction, i am not able to run the code..

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


    typedef unsigned int UINT32;

typedef struct
{
    UINT32 a : 4;
    UINT32 b: 2;
    UINT32 c: 2;
    UINT32 d: 4;
    UINT32 e: 4;
    UINT32 f: 8;
    UINT32 g: 8;
}Word;
Word *xx , *yy;

int main()
{
    xx = yy;
    xx->a = 1;
    printf("%d",xx->a);
    return 0;
}-- I am not able to run this code

Comment: `xx` and `yy` are pointers, so the `.` is wrong and should be replaced by `->`.

Comment: @alk, I was just editing for correcting it, I didn't notice it in the first place. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: i am using xx->a = 1; but still it does not work..

Answer (score 0):

I would do it simply like this:

```
#include <string.h>

Word A = { 4,2, 2,4,4,8,8};
Word B;
memcpy( &A, &B, sizeof(Word));
```

simple and effective.

**Edit:**
And even simpler is:

```
Word A = { 4,2, 2,4,4,8,8};
Word B = A;
```

Comment: Why are you doing `memcpy` when you could simply `B = A`?

Comment: Thats right i'll update

Answer (score 0):

your code copy the pointer so that `xx` and `yy` points to the same object.
if you would use structs (and not pointers) the = operator would by exactly as using `memcpy`

Here is the 2 pointers in the watch after the copy. Notice the same address
[image: Here is the 2 pointers in the watch after the copy. Notice the same address]

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the normal objects. Data cannot be initialized inside a structure implicitly in c. A object has to be created and data has to be fed in.

If the structure looks like this

```
typedef unsigned int UINT32;
struct Word{
  UINT32 a;
  UINT32 b;
  UINT32 c;
  UINT32 d;
 };
```

Without using pointers:

```
Word xx , yy={0,1,2,3};
xx = yy;
xx.a = 10;
yy.b = 100; 
printf("%d -- %d -- %d -- %d",yy.a,yy.b,yy.c,yy.d); // 0 -- 100 -- 2 -- 3 
printf("%d -- %d -- %d -- %d",xx.a,xx.b,xx.c,xx.d); // 10 -- 1 -- 2 -- 3
```

Here **xx** and **yy** are different objects created for Word. **yy** object data is copied to **xx**. When making changes to element of **xx** will not affect **yy** data because both are differnet objects.

When using pointers:

```
 struct Word *xx;
 struct Word *yy=malloc(sizeof(struct Word));
 yy->a=0;
 yy->b=1;
 yy->c=2;
 yy->d=3;
 xx=yy;
 xx->a = 10;
 yy->b = 100; 
 printf("%d -- %d -- %d -- %d",yy->a,yy->b,yy->c,yy->d); // 10 -- 100 -- 2 -- 3 
 printf("%d -- %d -- %d -- %d",xx->a,xx->b,xx->c,xx->d); // 10 -- 100 -- 2 -- 3
```

Here you have allocated memory for **xx** and initialized data to it. Both **xx** and **yy** point to a same memory location so changing data in either **xx** or **yy** will affect both.